# MySQL alias shorthand?

Tags: mysql, alias

I need to select all columns from two tables, but need to be able to differentiate between them in the result.

Is there a shorthand method of giving each column in the result an alias?

For example:

```
SELECT t1.* AS t1.SOMETHING
     , t2.* AS SOMETHING_ELSE 
  FROM TABLE1 
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 
    ON SOMETHING = SOMETHING_ELSE
```

In the results, all columns from table one would be prefixes t1, while all results from table two would be prefixes t2.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you'll need to name them explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

No, `ALIAS` is only for single columns. The only shorthand is to remove the `AS`:

```
SELECT column_123 col FROM x
```

Returns `col` as the alias.