# MySQL query to select * from multiple tables with ambiguous names

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

use these 2 tables:

table1:

- id
- name
- table2_id

table2:

- id
- name

then running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id=table2.id
```

the result includes the references:  id, name, table2_id, id, name... a "fetch_all" call to put those into an associative array would lose the duplicated values.

i would like the reference values returned prepending the table name to the column name... i can get the results in this limited case by doing:

```
SELECT table1.id AS table1_id, table1.name AS table1_name, 
       table2.id AS table2_id, table2.name AS table2_name 
FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id=table2.id
```

... but these queries are being generated by a platform that isn't aware of all of the column name from the tables.  postgresql would just prepend the table name with a "." character after it, so i would already get "table1.id" as the reference value in the query.  it doesn't seem like mysql supports anything like this.

i was hoping for something like:

```
SELECT table1.* AS table1_*, table2.* AS table2_* 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id=table2.id
```

or maybe just a MySQL flag that i'm missing to add the table name to the references

Comment: Nope, MySQL doesn't support that. Your only real hope is to query `information_schema.tables` and get the column names in application code to dynamically build the query. But if your platform doesn't have that flexibility (if it did, you should just write it manually) you don't have good options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL alias shorthand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478368/mysql-alias-shorthand) and also [MySql - Select * from 2 tables, but Prefix Table Names in the Resultset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797065/mysql-select-from-2-tables-but-prefix-table-names-in-the-resultset)

Comment: yes, this is a dupe of those other questions.  i'm coming from postgresql and find lack of support for this very saddening.  especially considering that returning the multiple columns with the same name is almost always saved to an associative array, so half the values are always lost... seems like a completely broken implementation... they even state all over the man page how it breaks from SQL standard... WHY?